# How to remove underline from <li> inside <Link>

Tags: hyperlink, html-lists

Home

How to fix this?

I want to change the underline and the text default color.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration
setting textdecoration to none will to the trick. Also setting the color CSS property.